# What are possible values for the FileSystemName string that GetVolumeInformation returns?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364993%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139547)  of GetVolumeInformation are not very specific what the file system name string can contain.

The obvious values are NTFS, CDFS and FAT32. But can it also detect other file systems and what would be the strings ?
I also read somewhere that sometimes version numbers are included in the string. Any idea regarding this ? I don't know the specifics anymore. :(

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function can detect the following file systems:

FAT, FAT32, NTFS, HPFS, CDFS, UDF, NWFS

As I can remember for my experiences in 3 years ago, ex2 or ex3 were not detectable at all on Windows XP SP3.

**Edit**

Since Vista SP2, there is also support for exFAT

Comment: Since Vista SP2, there is also `exFAT`