# Enumerate all partitions and test if they are NTFS

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ntfs, ntfs-mft

I'm using:

```
DWORD d = GetLogicalDrives();
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    if ((1 << i) & d) // drive letter 'A' + i present on computer
    {
        wstring s = std::wstring(L"\\\\.\\") + wchar_t('A' + i) + L":";

        PARTITION_INFORMATION diskInfo;
        DWORD dwResult;
        HANDLE dev = CreateFile(LPWSTR(s.c_str()), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY, NULL);
        DeviceIoControl(dev, IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO, NULL, 0, &diskInfo, sizeof(diskInfo), &dwResult, NULL);
        CloseHandle(dev);
        if (diskInfo.PartitionType == PARTITION_IFS) 
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

to enumerate all NTFS partitions of a computer.

It works on my Windows 7, on a Windows 8.1 I tried it on, and on a Windows 10 computer.

But it fails on another Windows 10 computer: on this one, the volume `C:` has a `diskInfo.PartitionType` value equal to `0x00`, instead of `0x07` (`PARTITION_IFS`).

This value is (see the [doc here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/disk-partition-types)):

> PARTITION_ENTRY_UNUSED : 0x00 : An unused entry partition.

This is strange, since, I can confirm, the partition is really NTFS.

Questions:

- **Is it well-known that `IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO` is not 100% reliable to get the partition type?**
- **What would be a more reliable way to enumerate all NTFS volumes?**

---

Note: I also looked at using [`IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO_EX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-ioctl_disk_get_partition_info_ex) instead of `IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO` but then the structure [`PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-_partition_information_ex) does not seem to give informations about `PartitionType`, whereas the structure [`PARTITION_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-_partition_information) does give access to [`PartitionType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/disk-partition-types).

Comment: You are not doing any error handling.  You are not checking to make sure that `CreateFile()` and `DeviceIoControl()` are actually successful before evaluating `diskInfo.PartitionType`. Another way to find NTFS partitions is to use `GetLogicalDrives/Strings()` and `GetVolumeInformation()`, the `lpFileSystemNameBuffer` parameter will return the name of the file system on each drive you query...

Comment: ... At the very least, you should use `GetLogicalDrives/Strings()` anyway. This will reduce the number of drives you attempt to query, even if you stick with `CreateFile()`/`DeviceIoControl()`. Instead of blindly trying all 26 letters of the alphabet, you only have to query the ones that have actually been assigned to a drive.

Comment: @RemyLebeau In fact in my original code, I did use `GetLogicalDrives`, I didn't include it here because I thought it was not relevant for the problem, but you're right: it's an important part, so I edited the question to include it. (Sorry, I should have included it before). With the current code, what would you change? If you have the possibility, could you post a sample code in an answer? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use a [`wmi` query](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10539/Making-WMI-Queries-In-C) to enumerate **all partitions**, something like following PowerShell `Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_Volume" -Namespace "ROOT\CIMV2" | Select-Object -Property DriveLetter, Label, FileSystem, DeviceId` (since Windows 8, use  `-namespace "ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Storage" -classname "MSFT_Volume"` and `-Property DriveLetter, FileSystemLabel, FileSystem, UniqueId`).

Comment: @JosefZ - wmi is very not efficent way, this is only remote call. for enumerate disks, volumes need enumerate interfaces via config api

Comment: and you need use `IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO_EX` for check partition type

Comment: @RbMm If possible, could you post a full code sample? Because I see many different techniques: `GetLogicalDrives`, `DeviceIoControl`, `IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO` vs. `IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO_EX`, `Get-WMiObject`, `GetVolumeInformationW`, etc. so we could easily get confused. A good answer would be very helpful for people who want to enumerate NTFS volumes in the future.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Or maybe you have a sample code (see previous comment)?

Comment: here is the question in the formulation of the problem. what is given, what to get. whether to associate the information with something. and more specific question. *wmi* of course not solution at all.

Comment: @Basj many different ways to tackle this.  So try them all and see which one works best for your situation and skillset.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I just inspected the return values. For `ret = DeviceIoControl(dev, IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO, NULL, 0, &diskInfo, sizeof(diskInfo), &lpBytesReturned, NULL);`, on the computer where it failed, I once got `0` `0` for `lpBytesReturned` and `ret`. After reboot, I had `2005860068` `0`. In both cases, `0` for `ret` indicates a failure. Any idea how I can investigate further?

Comment: @Basj You need to check the return value of `CreateFile()` before calling `DeviceIoControl()`. `CreateFile()` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` on failure. Also, you need to use `GetLastError()` to find out WHY each of these functions is failing. For example: `dev = CreateFile(...); if (dev == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { DWORD err = GetLastError(); ... } else { ret = DeviceIoControl(dev, ...); if (ret == FALSE) { DWORD err = GetLastError(); ... } CloseHandle(dev); }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you. I followed your advice, and investigation shows that `CreateFile` succeeds, and `DeviceIoControl` fails (returns `0` / `FALSE`). `GetLastError()` is `1`. I looked [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa365179(v=vs.90)) but I don't find the reason for the error.

Comment: @RbMm I also looked at using `IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO_EX` instead of `IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO` but then the structure [`PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX `](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-_partition_information_ex) does not seem to give informations about `PartitionType`, whereas the structure [`PARTITION_INFORMATION `](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-_partition_information) does give access to [`PartitionType`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/disk-partition-types).What do you think?

Comment: @RemyLebeau If you have a few minutes, do you think it's possible to chat (not very long). I spend the whole day on this, but I can't find the error ;) (see my previous message about GetLastError).

Comment: @Basj per [System Error Codes (0-499)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-), error code 1 is `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION`. That means `IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO` is not supported by the device you passed to `DeviceIoControl()`.

Comment: @Basj "*`PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX` does not seem to give informations about `PartitionType`*" - yes, it does. `PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX` has a `PartitionStyle` field that tells you whether to look at the `Mbr` or `Gpt` field for more information. Both of those structs have a `PartitionType` field. `Mbr.PartitionType` is a `BYTE`, `Gpt.PartitionType` is a `GUID`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190394/discussion-between-basj-and-remy-lebeau).

Comment: To the downvoter: it would be cool if you could leave a message about how to improve this question. I have done extensive research during hours, and I have now posted the result of the observations in an answer, and have tried to summarized comments together. It would be a shame that the question/answer gets roomba'd one day because of downvotes, thus loosing these reports of working+nonworking solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did further investigation thanks to @RemyLebeau's comments with:

```
HANDLE dev = CreateFile(..., GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY, NULL);

if (dev == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
{ 
    DWORD err = GetLastError();  // then MessageBox       
} 
else
{ 
    BOOL ret = DeviceIoControl(dev, IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO, NULL, 0, &diskInfo, sizeof(diskInfo), &dwResult, NULL);

    if (ret == FALSE) 
    { 
        DWORD err = GetLastError();  // then MessageBox
    } 
    CloseHandle(dev); 
}
```

on the computer where it failed (computer with Windows 10). I found that `CreateFile` succeeded but then `DeviceIoControl` failed with `GetLastError` being `1` i.e. `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION` (see [System Error Codes (0-499)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-)).

Conclusion (I quote Remy's comment):

> That means IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO is not supported by the device you passed to DeviceIoControl().

I then tried with `IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO_EX`:

```
PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX diskInfo;
BOOL ret = DeviceIoControl(dev, IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO_EX, NULL, 0, &diskInfo, sizeof(diskInfo), &lpBytesReturned, NULL);
```

and then it worked. I could see that `diskInfo.PartitionStyle` was `PARTITION_STYLE_GPT` (=1), and this was the reason why `IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO` failed. I quote Remy's comment again:

> IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO is not supported on GPT partitioned drives.

So here's the conclusion:

- use `IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO_EX` instead of `IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO`

  - if `diskInfo.PartitionStyle` is 0 (PARTITION_STYLE_MBR) then diskInfo.Mbr.PartitionType can be tested. [If it's 0x07, it's NTFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/disk-partition-types).
  - if `diskInfo.PartitionStyle` is 1 (PARTITION_STYLE_GPT) then diskInfo.Gpt.PartitionType can be tested, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-_partition_information_gpt. Even if the [NTFS Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) mentions the GUID `EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7` for NTFS in the GPT case, this GUID is in fact unrelated to file system (see comment below about this).
- it's probably easier to use `GetVolumeInformation()` instead and just compare if the result is the `"NTFS"` string, as in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55255172)
- in my particular case, I initially wanted to test if a volume is NTFS or not *before* attempting an indexing with `DeviceIoControl(hVol, FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA, ...)` because I thought such MFT querying would be limited to NTFS volumes. In fact, **an easier solution would be to NOT TEST if it's NTFS or not**, and just do the `FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA`. The worst that can happen is that `FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA` fails with `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION` error, per the documentation:

  > "ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION The file system on the specified volume does not support this control code."

Comment: look for `PARTITION_BASIC_DATA_GUID` definition in *diskguid.h*. this (*EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7*) not mean *ntfs* partition. this is unrelated to file system

Comment: @RbMm Ok I'll remove this part in my answer. Feel free to post a better answer, I'm still interested.

Comment: and you not need test ntfs this or not before send `FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA`

Comment: @RbMm yes that's what I mentioned in my last paragraph, thanks for this precision.

Answer (score 1):

As @RemyLebeau says, you are not checking the return value for each call.

`PARTITION_ENTRY_UNUSED` often means the `DeviceIoControl()` call failed. It depends on the permissions of your user. You should check your user's access rights to see if it has the `FILE_READ_DATA` permission (included in `GENERIC_READ`) on volume `C:`. In my test environment, if you have no access to open volume `C:` with `GENERIC_READ`, `CreateFile()` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, and then `DeviceIoControl()` fails as well.

EDIT:

I suggest using `GetVolumeInformation()`, for example:

```
wchar_t fs[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
GetVolumeInformationW(L"C:\\", NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, fs, MAX_PATH + 1);
```

And you will see the Type info in the `fs` buffer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @DrakeWu-MSFT. Which solution would you suggest to enumerate reliably the NTFS partitions? Note: The software I'm working on is *always* run as administrator (so user permission should not be a problem).

Comment: So, could you make sure the calls are successful. I suggest to use `GetVolumeInformation()`. See my edit.

Comment: it works with `GetVolumeInformationW` @DrakeWu-MSFT, I found `"NTFS"` in `fs`. Is it reliable to test if `fs` is equal to `NTFS`? Or can it be `"ntfs"` as well on some versions of Windows?

Comment: @Basj does it really matter? Just use a case-insensitive comparison.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I mean in general, is it documented to be always `"NTFS"` or are there versions of Windows for which it could be `NTFS-something` or `IFS` or anything slight variation meaning the same thing? (You gave a better solution in chat, but this question is interesting independently).

Comment: @Basj the names are not formally documented by MS, that I know of, but have a look at [What are possible values for the FileSystemName string that GetVolumeInformation returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106679/).